# open popup with asp.net menu control

Tags: asp.net, menu, popup

Hi guys i have a terrible problem
İ have to open popup window(javascript) with asp.net menu control but i cant.Menu items dont contains "attribute" so i cant assign javascript codes.
How can i solve?
thx your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can set Javascript calls in the NavigateURL property

```
menuItem.NavigateUrl = String.Format("javascript:openPopup('{0}');", sURL);
```

Comment: i try but my main page nagivates a blank page.
my code is:
 <siteMapNode title="LiveResults" url="javascript:popup('Reports/RaceResultsPopup.aspx')"/>

Comment: I assume you popup(v1) on the page correctly. and that is the correct address?